# problems with using the scanner class. After System.out.println("Please enter the score of student 1");, it skips two questions

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
package findingthehighestscore;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindingTheHighestScore
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    // store students names  
    String student1;
    String student2;
    String student3;
    String tempStudent;

    // store students scores
    double score1;
    double score2;
    double score3;
    double tempScore;

    //Prompt user for input of each student and their score
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of Student 1");
    student1 = kybd.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the score of student 1");
    score1 = kybd.nextByte();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of Student 2");
    student2 = kybd.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the score of student 2");
    score2 = kybd.nextByte();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of Student 3");
    student3 = kybd.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the score of student 3");
    score3 = kybd.nextByte();

    //if score2 is greater then score1 then swap scores. Score 1 will be printed as highest score
    if(score2 > score1)
    {
       tempScore = score1;      
       score1 = score2;
       score2 = tempScore;           
       tempStudent = student1;           
       student1 = student2;          
       student2 = tempStudent;          
    }

     //if score3 is greater then score1 then swap scores.
    if(score3 > score1)
    {
       tempScore = score1;
       score1 = score3;          
       score3 = tempScore;           
       tempStudent = student1;           
       student1 = student3;           
       student3 = tempStudent;           
    }        
    System.out.print(student1 + " has the highest score of " + score1);       
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Replace :-

```
student1 = kybd.nextLine();
```

with: -

```
student1 = kybd.next();
```

**nextLine()** method doesn't read the **newline** character at the end of the current input.. So, the newline is left to read on the next `scanner.nextByte()` invocation.. Which does not read a byte but the newline..

So, it basically skips the next line (As it **reads newline** left from previous input) and advances the cursor after next line.. So, your `nextByte()` method is just **skipped**..

So, to read the newline you can use `next()` method.. This way, nothing will be left to read on next iteration..

Comment: Thanks for the solution but can you explain the reasoning in simpler terms as I am a beginner programmer.

Comment: @user1718135.. I have explained in my post.. Read it.. `scanner.nextLine()` reads the current line, but skips the `newline(\n)` at the end of the line.. So, that new line is read when we try to read next user input.. So, if you do `sc.nextByte()` it will actually read the `newline(\n)` left on the prevoius input.. That's why it is skipped.. As it has already read user input `(\n)`..